# Local application with maps

Tags: java, wpf, google-maps, maps, desktop-application

I'm currently building a web application using Google Maps. Unfortunately, I've reached the absolute maximum limit that Javascript will reach for all of the different things I'd like to do, and we're exploring all of the alternatives.

We've looked at server-side caching and pre-generation/computing. It's definitely a possibility, but supposedly even that is 'too slow' while trying to plot 100k+ points in one go. As everything (as always) needs to always load instantly (or as near as darnit), I'm looking at a local application as an alternative.

Before I put forward the idea (which I already know that everyone will go for), there are two things I'm looking at first:

1. Can I use Google Maps locally?
2. I want to take the application between just PC and Mac. I'm a WPF and Web developer. Windows side, fine. Mac, however, doesn't play so nicely with those technologies. Is it time for me to bite the bullet and learn Java?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea if this meets [their TOS](http://www.google.com/help/terms_maps.html), but you could look into: http://www.howtogeek.com/90565/how-to-download-google-maps-for-offline-use/

Java AFAIK is the most main-stream high level cross-platform language for desktop applications.

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) install rate on macs is probably extremely low in comparison to Java, though [that might not be a problem if you use mkbundle](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications).  and [WPF isn't supported](http://www.mono-project.com/WPF) (though [GTK#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp) is).  You could do Silverlight/[Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight), which [are supported outside the browser](http://www.mono-project.com/WPF), and quite similar to WPF.

You could also look at using C++ or Python with [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/).  Though if you go with Python, there [are a ton of GUI libraries for it](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming).

Comment: Yeah, I looked very briefly at Mono, but then looking at my own Mac, I figured very, very quickly 'no, that's not going to happen'. Not sure about C++, don't particularly want to go down that route (thinking garbage collection etc.). I said Java because of it's basic closeness to C#... Python though... hum.

Comment: Oh, found mkbundle.  Added it to my answer.  I'd do proofs of concept before going all the way with any complete rewrite of an app, for sure.  Python, Java, and Mono all have a potential for being sluggish.  And getting Python installed on Windows might be something clients don't want to do (maybe work-arounds for that, though I haven't looked into them)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, your map application involves plotting 100,000+ markers (latitude/longitude points) on a single map. You presently draw the markers on the map using JavaScript code and function calls.

Consider sticking with web-hosted Google Maps, and using one of two alternate implementation approaches.

1. Aggregate points. You can try drawing 100 markers onto the same screen pixel, but the user won't get any more information than if you just drew one marker. Consider aggregating multiple closely-spaced markers into aggregate markers. Google's docs have suggestions about how to do this in "Too Many Markers!", by Luke Mahe and Chris Broadfoot, Google Geo APIs Team, December 2010 (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/toomanymarkers.html).
2. Draw markers yourself onto custom map tiles. I'm involved with a maps application which uses the Webfoot Map Tile Generator code, which takes this approach to draw approx 50,000 dots on a map of the continental US marking the location of each US Zip Code. See (http://maps.webfoot.com/demos/election2008/), and in the left pane, under "Dots Layer", select "Zip Codes" in the pull-down menu. Drawing your own map tiles isn't easy, but it's very powerful, and the Webfoot code shows it can be fast. Google doesn't completely document how to do this. But start with their description of implementing "your own custom map type using GMapType" (code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#CustomMapTiles) in the Maps Javascript API v2.  The equivalent for the Javascript API v3 appears to be missing from (code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomMapTypes).